# Find the partial sum of a given series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I found this thread, but since it says that I can't ask for help there, I'm making a new one.
[How to find the partial sum of a given series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124277/how-to-find-the-partial-sum-of-a-given-series/124278#124278?newreg=592458c6dc8c435a975d6c74d1dad619)

I have this series [(WolframAlpha)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?_=1387115335321&i=sum+from+n%3d3+to+infinity+%281%2f%28n%28n-2%29%29%29+&fp=1&incTime=true):
$$ \sum_{n = 3}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n - 2)} $$

And I need the partial sum formula. I don't get how it is derived. I got to the partial fraction decomposition described in the linked thread. I made it to the point where I ahd to put the newly found coefficients into the sum. This is what I got:
[(WolframAlpha)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28sum+from+n%3D3+to+k+%281%2F%282%28n-2%29%29+%29%29%29+-+%28sum+from+n%3D3+to+k+%281%2F%282n%29%29).
Ignore the output. Now how do I get from it to the partial sum formula in the first Wolfram Alpha link?

Answer (score 3):

Set 
$$a_n := \frac{1}{n(n - 2)} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{n - 2} - \frac{1}{n})$$
and $S_m := \sum_{n = 3}^m a_n$ for $n, m \geq 3$. From the partial fraction decomposition, the middle parts cancel each other. For example,
$$ \begin{align*}
S_5 &= \frac{1}{2}\Big((\frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{3}) + (\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4}) + (\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{5})\Big) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \Big( \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{5}\Big).  
\end{align*}$$

Similarly, we get 
$$ \begin{align*}
S_m &= \frac{1}{2} \Big(\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{m - 1} - \frac{1}{m} \Big) \\
&= \frac{3m^2 - 7m + 2}{4m(m - 1)}.
\end{align*}$$